# How to cross compile a C program that includes kernel headers

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to test the CVE-2016-8645 in my development board (ARMV7) Boundary devices sabrelite. I got this reproducer code from http://www.spinics.net/lists/stable/msg150470.html

It compiles with host GCC. But when I cross compile for ARM it fails missing headers. I pointed the header files using -I still it is missing.

> armv7l-linux-gnueabi-gcc poc.c -isystem /home/kernel-headers/include/linux/
>   In file included from poc.c:32:0:
>   /home/kernel-headers/include/linux/fcntl.h:4:30: fatal error: uapi/linux/fcntl.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>                                 ^
>   compilation terminated.

Comment: Why not compile it on the board itself? Quad core, 1GB RAM etc should be good enough.

Comment: Tried compiling in board also. Same error

Comment: May be try downloading linux source and point the include to <path-to-linux-source>/include/. Does uapi/linux/fcntl.h exist in the path specified in your command? It's also interesting that it compiles with host GCC...

Comment: are those the correct kernel headers?

Comment: The application is for user-space, why are you on earth trying to use kernel include path for it???